# node.js, socket.io only working on localhost, can't access from intranet

Tags: node.js, socket

I am using node.js and socket.io for the real time notification system. I have tested node.js and socket.io with simple chat code, it pretty good with localhost but can't access the same from the another system which are connected locally with same network. My server and client code looks like below:

`server.js`

```
var express = require('express')
 , app = express()
 , http = require('http')
 , server = http.createServer(app)
 , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

 server.listen(8888);
```

and client html `index.html`

```
<script src="http://localhost:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
</script>
```

It is working on my browser with this url `http://localhost/schat/index.html`, but not working when I am trying to connect from another one system using my ip `192.171.56.23/schat/index.html`. But all other html files are working fine, below is my netstat output:

```
[root@localhost schat]# netstat -pan | grep 8888
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN        8068/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          127.0.0.1:38273         ESTABLISHED 8068/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38273         127.0.0.1:8888          ESTABLISHED 7990/firefox
```

Comment: If it goes with a turned off firewall, your problem is solved (turning off firewall is acceptable only on a separated development network). If somebody closes your question, give a new try on http://unix.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Try **telnet 192.171.56.23 8888** from the remote machine, if you don't get a empty screen that means resquests to 8888 are not accepted.

Comment: got this output from remote `Trying 192.171.56.23...
Connected to 192.171.56.23.
Escape character is '^]'.`

Comment: what about **telnet 192.171.56.23 80**,  what is the error you get in the browser when connecting from the other machine

Comment: telnet 192.171.56.23 80 also working from remote, but when i'm running index.html from remote by using my ip instead of local host, it's showing html codes corectly but can't add new data i mean node.js and socket.io is not working, i think it's not listening node server

Comment: I don't have an experience with Node, but is there any ip-adresse binding to set in the Node config?

Answer (score 2):

After some above comments :

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
</script>
```

To be able to run your Node client on any remote machine, you have to change **localhost** with the **actual IP of the server**

Same thing for:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: yeah, i tried with this `var socket = io.connect('http://192.171.56.23:8888');` but it's not working even in local

Comment: first make the same for **<script src=..**, and if not working then it must be something dealing with ip-adress binding in the Node config.

Comment: i make the changes also in script scr, bu not fixing

Comment: is there any others params other than the port for **server.listen(8888);**

Comment: no, `server.listen(8888);` only

Comment: server.listen(8888, "0.0.0.0") will probably fix your issue.